# xmlhttp.setRequestHeader not working

Tags: java, ajax, servlets, character-encoding

this is my code

```
// assume var data has japanese characters
xmlhttp.open("POST","adminUpdate?&value="+data,true); // tried GET as well
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
xmlhttp.send();
```

if I insert alert(data) then i can see japanese characters perfectly fine.

But on the server side (servlet class) when I add this code  :

```
String query = request.getParameter("value");
system.out.println(query)
```

Now I see garbage value ??????

Ok so I added this line server side :

```
System.out.println("content type : "+ request.getContentType());
```

and I got this : `text/plain;charset=UTF-8`

So now my question is if the encoding is set correctly then why I cant see Japanese characters

Comment: machine ??? please explain your question. I can see japanese characters in my web page from database, as well if i hard code japanese characters then also i can see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to send the query parameters as part of the request body and have the content type set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Then, before getting the parameter, set the [request's content character encoding](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setCharacterEncoding%28java.lang.String%29)

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
String query = request.getParameter("value");
```

Note that wherever you're printing the `query` value has to be able to display `UTF-8` encoded characters.

Comment: and how to "send the query parameters as part of the request body" ??

Comment: @HarendraSingh `XmlHttpRequest` has a number of `send` methods. [Check them out here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). Use the appropriate one.

Comment: I think thats what am doing, sending the parameters is the request body using xmlhttp.send(); Your link's first command is this only

Comment: @HarendraSingh What you're currently doing is sending the request parameters as part of the query string. (There's a solution for that, but it's more complicated.) Instead, send the request parameters as form parameters. See the overloaded methods.

Comment: can you suggest an example I tried many but am got getting anywhere

Comment: @HarendraSingh [Here you go.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/sending-post-data-with-a-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: I didnt think that it was that easy, feeling dumb. +1 for the example